# How to retrieve last price of a items in a query using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing the `Items` (code, name, prices), when I use Access database I can write a query (Query by Example-QBE) and pick all these columns and grouping them for the last one which is prices I can use last function in QBE and it will easily after running, it will show distinct values of items with the last value of prices...

But when I try to do that I shocked when I don't find a function name like (last()), and after searching it made it complicated for me.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: There are functions called `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE`; are those what you are after?

Comment: Or perhaps you want the [top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)?

Comment: provide sample data and show us your desired output

Comment: I want to make a short list of all items with the last price of them:
lets say:
itemCode:1,pen has the following prices:1,2,4,5
itemCode:2,book has the following prices:4,1,2,1

if I use access I will be able to retreive the following:
itemCode:1,pen last price: 5
itemCode:2,book last price:1

but their is not such function